# UID Validation - Verhoeff's Algorithm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access & SQL.

I wish to validate 0.1 Mn UID Numbers (Aadhar Cards) for their authenticity.

The UID is based on Verhoeff's Algorithm.

I did find some queries online. They pertained to C++/Java.

Is there a query which validates 0.1 Mn in MS Access for SQL?

Comment: you have tagged "javascript" so post some code what u have tried

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm#JavaScript

Comment: I found a query here for Javascript.. but do not have much clue on how to use it.

Comment: You found the JavaScript version, but there is also a [VBA version](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm#VB_for_Applications) from the same source. Once you copied that code into a VBA module you could use the `validateVerhoeff()` function in an Access query.

Comment: I used the VBA script given in the link. However, i am getting only random values ie. 0 & -1 . Eg; for 97424234030..the validation checksum is 7 however, the query gives the result as -1.  Is the execution wrong? Can you kindly test this sample number with the given query on the link.

Comment: `validateVerhoeff()` returns a Boolean (0=False, -1=True) indicating whether the supplied string is valid. If you want to generate the checksum digit you need to use `generateVerhoeff()`. I just tested it and `generateVerhoeff("97424234030")` does indeed return `7`.

Comment: Actually worked...Thanks a ton..!!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Gord Thempson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) in the comments, you can find the VBA (and many more implementation on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm#VB_for_Applications)

For the sake of completeness,

```
''' <summary>
''' For more information cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm
''' Dihedral Group: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralGroup.html
''' You can use this code in Excel, Access, etc...
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>

'The multiplication table
Dim d(0 To 9) As Variant
'The permutation table
Dim p(0 To 8) As Variant
'The inverse table
Dim inv(0 To 9) As Integer

Private Sub initVerhoeffConsts()
    If IsArray(d(0)) Then Exit Sub 'Shortcut if already initiated
    d(0) = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    d(1) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5)
    d(2) = Array(2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6)
    d(3) = Array(3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7)
    d(4) = Array(4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    d(5) = Array(5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1)
    d(6) = Array(6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2)
    d(7) = Array(7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3)
    d(8) = Array(8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4)
    d(9) = Array(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

    p(0) = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    p(1) = Array(1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4)
    p(2) = Array(5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2)
    p(3) = Array(8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7)
    p(4) = Array(9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0)
    p(5) = Array(4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1)
    p(6) = Array(2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5)
    p(7) = Array(7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8)

    inv(0) = 0: inv(1) = 4: inv(2) = 3: inv(3) = 2: inv(4) = 1
    inv(5) = 5: inv(6) = 6: inv(7) = 7: inv(8) = 8: inv(9) = 9
End Sub


''' <summary>
''' Validates that an entered number is Verhoeff compliant.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="num"></param>
''' <returns>True if Verhoeff compliant, otherwise false</returns>
''' <remarks>Make sure the check digit is the last one!</remarks>
Public Function validateVerhoeff(ByVal num As String) As Boolean
        initVerhoeffConsts
        Dim c As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        c = 0
        Dim myArray() As Integer
        myArray = StringToReversedIntArray(num)

        For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
            c = d(c)(p((i Mod 8))(myArray(i)))  'Version corrected by WHG gives error
        Next i

        validateVerhoeff = (c = 0)
End Function


''' <summary>
''' For a given number generates a Verhoeff digit
''' </summary>
''' <param name="num"></param>
''' <returns>Verhoeff check digit as Integer</returns>
''' <remarks>Append this check digit to num</remarks>
Public Function generateVerhoeff(ByVal num As String) As Integer
    initVerhoeffConsts
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer    
    c = 0
    Dim myArray() As Integer
    myArray = StringToReversedIntArray(num)

    For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        c = d(c)(p((i + 1) Mod 8)(myArray(i)))   'Version corrected by WHG gives error in compilation
    Next i

    generateVerhoeff = inv(c) 'str(inv(c))
End Function


''' <summary>
''' Converts a string to a reversed integer array.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="str"></param>
''' <returns>Reversed integer array</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function StringToReversedIntArray(ByVal str As String) As Integer()
    Dim lg As Integer
    lg = Len(str)
    Dim myArray() As Integer
    ReDim myArray(0 To lg - 1)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To lg - 1
        myArray(i) = AscW(Mid$(str, lg - i, 1)) - AscW("0")
    Next
    StringToReversedIntArray = myArray
End Function

''' In Excel don't copy this sub _AssertsVerhoeff()as get a compilation error. 4/21/2013
Public Sub _AssertsVerhoeff()
    Debug.Print "Start Verhoeff's Asserts"
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("75872") = 2
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("758722") = True
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("12345") = 1
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("123451") = True
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("142857") = 0
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("1428570") = True
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("123456789012") = 0
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("1234567890120") = True
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("8473643095483728456789") = 2
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("84736430954837284567892") = True
    Debug.Assert generateVerhoeff("12345") = 1
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("123451") = True
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("124351") = False
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("122451") = False
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("128451") = False
    Debug.Assert validateVerhoeff("214315") = False
    Debug.Print "End Verhoeff's Asserts"
End Sub
```